# Evaluating multiple OR conditions

Tags: julia

Due to short circuit rules I can't write something like the this:

```
message = "nada"

if message != "success" || message != "login successful"
    error("get_response() failed with message returned of: $message")
end
```

Instead I've had to write the something like this to get it working:

```
message = "nada"

if message != "success" ? message != "login successful" : false
    error("get_response() failed with message returned of: $message")
end
```

The second way seems ... "clunky", so I feel like I've missed something when going through the julia manual. Is there a standard way to write multiple OR conditions? (or a better way to write multiple OR conditions than what I have).

Assume the `message` could be any string, and I only want to do something if it isn't `"success"` or `"login successful"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply seems to be a mistake in the use of or/and vs negations. I guess that what you wanted was

```
message = "nada"

if !(message == "success" || message == "login successful")
    error("get_response() failed with message returned of: $message")
end
```

or equivalently

```
message = "nada"

if message != "success" && message != "login successful"
    error("get_response() failed with message returned of: $message")
end
```

which both work for me. The original condition

```
message != "success" || message != "login successful"
```

is always true since any `message` has to be unequal to at least one of the strings `"success"` and `"login successful"`.

Comment: *face palm* ... this is why you don't code too late at night ladies and gentlemen.